# Google Plus button Image update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-plus

I have a gallery page where there is a main page and small thumbs when they click on the small thumb it will display it on the main image section however my google+ button will only reflect the first Image on page load and when the image is change it does not update the new image.

Any help would be great Thank you.

My code

its in a string builder

```
<div id='divGPlusone' class='g-plusone' data-size='medium' data-annotation='inline' data-width='300' data-href='http://" & siteURL & "'></div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to +1 the main page and have +1s for unique images that are loaded dynamically. The +1 button code you have in your question suffices for the main page +1.

Each time your user clicks on a image, you would want to either dynamically create a new +1 button for the image or change the `data-href` parameter for the existing button. Which option you pick might decide on the design of your page. I'll give examples for both approaches:

**Inserting a new +1 button dynamically for the image:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Assuming you have an existing method that is swapping the images.
  function loadImage() {
    // Existing image swap code runs

    // Assume you have a URL that can be externally referenced and points directly
    // to the unique image rather than to the main page, otherwise, doesn't make a 
    // lot of sense to +1 it.
    var uniqueImagePage = 'http://example.com/gallery/image005.html';

    // Dynamically render a new +1 button
    // First insert a node to attach the button to.
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'image005';

    // Assume you have a container element that your image also goes into
    var container = document.getElementById('imgContainer');

    // Append the new +1 button into that container
    container.appendChild(div);

    var plusOneOptions = {
      'href' : uniqueImagePage,
      'width' : '300'
      // Any other params
    };
    gapi.plusone.render('image005',plusOneOptions);
  }
</script>
```

**Changing an existing +1 button's URL dynamically**

We'll assume that your existing +1 button has an ID associated with its DIV:

```
<div
  id="imagePlusOneButton"
  class="g-plusone"
  data-href="http://example.com/oldurl.html">
</div>
```

Then you would change the URL when you swap images in your gallery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Assuming you have an existing method that is swapping the images.
  function loadImage() {
    // Run existing image swap code.

    // Change the +1 button URL
    var plusDiv = document.getElementById('imagePlusOneButton');

    // Change URLs associated with the current button
    plusDiv.setAttribute('data-href','http://example.com/newUrl.html');

  }
</script>
```

This method can work with the first method too if you don't want to inject new +1 buttons for every image but rather have one for the main page and one for the currently displayed image.

The [`gapi.plusone.render()` method](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#jsapi) is the one you'll need to do anything dynamic with the +1 button. Sometimes you'll also need to set the global configuration parameter `parseTags` to `explicit` depending on when you want tags to render.